# Click javascript button to add friend

Tags: javascript, sql, database, web

On Facebook you can click on the "add friend" button to add a friend without refreshing the page. Presumably this involves accessing a database using JavaScript, but I was given to understand that that is a bad idea.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Ajax basicly

1. User click button
2. Javascript open another page at background like "addfriend.php?id=5"
3. PHP page add request to Database
4. PHP (or any server page) return answer
5. Javascript handle answer

Comment: This was similar to what I imagined it could have been.
There were so many answers that were helpful but this step by step answer was the most clear so I chose this,
Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly interacting with the database but with an API ( some web service ).
The API then has logic within it to then interact with the database.

Comment: This. Calling a web service from JavaScript is not any more dangerous than calling it via any HTTP request. The point is to put something between the browser and the database to limit what the client can do.

Answer (score 1):

They do not allow database access from javascript, they are simple making HTTP calls from javascript, without loading entire page. The technology is called AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). You can read more about AJAX [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

It would have been bad if the SQL for the database would be specified in the client code and executed without any validation against the DB:

```
<input type="button" onclick="updateDatabase('INSERT INTO FriendRequests...')" />
```

...but that is not the case.

Very simplified: The 'add friend' button calls a server-side method via an HTTP request. The server-side method verifies your identity and the request, then probably calls a data-access method, and the data-access method then calls the underlying database. So this is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaScript causes the browser to make an HTTP request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) behind the scenes (this is usually known as Ajax), and a server side process handles the database access.